# How replicate rails console output style in runner script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pry

When running `User.first` in the rails console I will get a beautiful output, something like:

[image: beautiful output in rails console]

I assume this is taken care of by pry. How can I get the same output styling when using the runner? Consider a file `tinker.rb`

```
u = User.first
puts u
```

and running it like: `rails r './tinker.rb`. While it will output something, it is not as polished as in the console:

```
#<User:0x00007fc6518acec8>
```

How can I make it *exactly* the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formatting is a result of PrettyPrint module - `PP`:

```
u = User.first
pp u #=> Which is basically a shortcut for: PP.pp(u)
```

Note however, that by default this will not generate a colourful output. Pry additionally process the formatted string through another gem - coderay, which is responsible for ruby syntax highlighting. If you want to print in colour, then:

```
u = User.first
Pry::ColorPrinter.pp(u)
```